# How do i break the loop for this UniswapV3 bot when my balance has decreased by 10% from original balance

Tags: blockchain, solidity, ethers.js, uniswap

So i made a bot that will continuously do multi hop swaps on the Uniswap V3 DAI and USDC 0.05% pool, as a result each trade the bot makes will effectively make me lose around 0.10% of my balance each time.

I want the bot to stop trading when my current balance is 90% of my original balance that i started of with but i don't know how to do that.

so far i've hard written 90% of my test balance into the if statement, but this is not ideal if i have a different balance each time i turn the bot on.

```
const { expect } = require("chai");
const { ethers, network} = require('hardhat')


const DAI = '0x6B175474E89094C44Da98b954EedeAC495271d0F';
const DAI_WHALE = '0xF977814e90dA44bFA03b6295A0616a897441aceC';

function waitforme(milisec) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(() => { resolve('') }, milisec);
  })
}

describe("SwapExamples", () => {
  let swapExamples
  let dai
  let whale
  let accounts
  before(async () => {
    
    const SwapExamples = await ethers.getContractFactory("SwapExamples")
    swapExamples = await SwapExamples.deploy()
    await swapExamples.deployed()

    dai = await ethers.getContractAt("IERC20", DAI)
    whale = await ethers.getSigner(DAI_WHALE)
    accounts = await ethers.getSigners()

    await network.provider.request({
      method: "hardhat_impersonateAccount",
      params: [DAI_WHALE],
    })

    
  })

  it("unlock account", async () => {
    const amount = 100n * 10n ** 18n

    console.log("DAI balance of whale", await dai.balanceOf(DAI_WHALE))
    expect(await dai.balanceOf(DAI_WHALE)).to.gte(amount)

    await dai.connect(whale).transfer(accounts[0].address, amount)

    console.log(
      "DAI balance of account",
      await dai.balanceOf(accounts[0].address)
    )
  })

it("swapExactInputMultihop", async () => {
 
  for (let i = 0; i < 111; i++) {
    if ( await dai.balanceOf(accounts[0].address) <= 90000000000000000000) { break;}
    const amountIn = await dai.balanceOf(accounts[0].address)

  await dai.approve(swapExamples.address, amountIn)
  // Swap
  await swapExamples.swapExactInputMultihop(amountIn)
  
  console.log("DAI balance", await dai.balanceOf(accounts[0].address))
  
  await waitforme(1000);  
} 
}).timeout(500000)
})
```

instead of having the :

```
if ( await dai.balanceOf(accounts[0].address) <= 90000000000000000000){break;}
```

i want it so the loop breaks when the original balance of account[0] is down by 10%. This is to ensure any value of dai that is in a the account can use the bot.

Comment: To begin with, put the `await promise` expression inside parenthesis.

Comment: Second, the returned value is a `BigNumber` object, so you should use `lte` instead of `<=`.

Comment: Third, to answer your actual question, start by recording `const x = await dai.balanceOf(accounts[0].address)` before the loop.

Comment: Then you can use `.lte(x.mul(90).div(100))` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const balance = await dai.balanceOf(accounts[0].address);
for (let i = 0; i < 111; i++) {
    const amountIn = await dai.balanceOf(accounts[0].address)
    if (amountIn.mul(10).lte(balance.mul(9))) {
        break;
    }
    // the rest of your code goes here...
}
```

See the comments that I left on your question for more details...